# Integral $\int \frac{1}{x\ln(x-2)} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to evaluate $\int \frac{1}{x\ln(x-2)} d x + \frac{1}{(x-2)\ln(x-2)} dx$

I tried using substitution $u = x-2 \iff dx = \frac{du}{x-2}$

And ended up with

$$\int \frac{1}{x\ln(x-2)} dx + \ln(\ln(x-2)) + c_1 $$

Still I have a hard time calculating
$$\int \frac{1}{x\ln(x-2)} dx $$

Any ideas?

---

**A different approach that may work**

$\int \frac{1}{x\ln(x-2)}  + \frac{1}{(x-2)\ln(x-2)} dx = (-\frac{1}{2}) \int \frac{\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x-2}}{ln(x-2)} dx =  \int \frac{1}{x(x-2)ln(x-2)} dx$

This seems easier but still I can't evaluate it.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=primitive+1%2F+ln%28x-2%29+*+%281%2Fx+%2B+1%2F%28x-2%29%29) does not found a result in term of elementary functions. Are you sure there is?

Comment: @sewer It is a textbook unsolved exercise. It wouldn't make sense to not be elementary. I am actually trying to find an intergrating factor in order to turn a non-exact differential equation into an exact. I am trying to find a workaround by doing the following $\int \frac{1}{x\ln(x-2)} d x + \frac{1}{(x-2)\ln(x-2)} dx = (-\frac{1}{2}) \int \frac{\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x-2}}{ln(x-2)} dx =  \int \frac{1}{x(x-2)ln(x-2)} dx$

This seems easier but still I can't solve it.

Comment: Note: The integrating factor would be $ρ(x) = e^{ \int \frac{1}{x(x-2)ln(x-2)} dx} $. Maybe we could do something clever with the exponential? No idea

Comment: Integrals are evaluated , not solved.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Check the second comment

Comment: Oh... without the first $dx$, my bad. Everything is inside the integral

Comment: @Dimitris What differential equation are you trying to solve???

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose I am solving the following differential equation: $\left( \frac{y}{x} + 6x \right) dx + (ln(x)-2)dy = 0$ where $M(x,y) = \frac{y}{x} + 6x$ and $N(x,y) = ln(x)-2$ we notice that: $\frac{\partial M(x,y)}{\partial y} \neq \frac{\partial N(x,y)}{\partial x}  $ therefore the differential equation is not exact. We need to find an intergrating factor $ρ(x)$ in order to turn it into an exact differential equation. We know that if $\frac{\frac{\partial M(x,y)}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial N(x,y)}{\partial x}}{N(x,y)} = P(x)$ then $ρ(x) = e^{\int P(x) dx}$.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Therefore $\frac{\frac{\partial M(x,y)}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial N(x,y)}{\partial x}}{N(x,y)} = P(x) =  \frac{1}{x(x-2)ln(x-2)}  \iff \int P(x) dx =  \int \frac{1}{x(x-2)ln(x-2)} dx $

Comment: In short the problem said: "Solve $\left( \frac{y}{x} + 6x \right) dx + (ln(x)-2)dy = 0$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhhh we have found your problem. The differential equation is already exact. Double check the derivatives. ${\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln(x)-2\right) = \frac{1}{x}}$, and also
${\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{y}{x}+6x\right)=\frac{1}{x}}$

Comment: Oh god haha. Thanks a lot, you saved the day

Comment: No problem at all :D